# docx4j import style from other .docx problem

Tags: java, import, styles, docx4j

I get code from here: [Docx4j export style from one .docx and use it in another .docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35135679/docx4j-export-style-from-one-docx-and-use-it-in-another-docx)

```
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage2 = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/template.docx"));

MainDocumentPart tempDocPart = wordMLPackage2.getMainDocumentPart();
StyleDefinitionsPart sdp = tempDocPart.getStyleDefinitionsPart();
Styles tempStyle = sdp.getJaxbElement();

wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getStyleDefinitionsPart().setJaxbElement(tempStyle);
```

So I import the style from template.docx, where I created my own Heading1 ant Title style. Its working, I have problem in the following code:

```
wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addStyledParagraphOfText("Title", "Title test");
```

If I add this pharagraph, in the created .docx file the Title style will be the default docx4j style, but the Heading1 will be the same as in the template.docx.
If I change the "Title" to "Heading1", I have the same problem, but the Heading1 style will be the default and Title will be the imported style.
So If I add styled paragraph in the code, the style will change to default style, but if I dont add styled paragraph and I open the created docx in Word and change the text style, it will be the imported style.

Comment: You've replaced all the styles.

Comment: Yea, but as I wrote, when I write styled paragraph, that style will be the default, not the replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution. I use Word in hungarian language, and the "Heading1" in hungarian is "Címsor1."

So instead of this:

```
wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addStyledParagraphOfText("Heading1", "Test");
```

I have to use this:

```
wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addStyledParagraphOfText("Cmsor1", "Test");
```